# NHibernate NonUniqueObjectException when reattaching objects to the session (with Lock)

Tags: nhibernate, session, object-persistence

Basic order of execution:

1. A collection of `PersistentObjects` is queried then cached separately from the session.
2. The collection is passed to a module that needs to reattach them to the session in order to lazily load some of the properties (using `session.Lock(obj, LockMode.None)`).
3. After the module has completed processing, another module attempts to `SaveOrUpdate` a `UserSetting` object with some usage statistics for the user who initialized the action.
4. On `session.Flush()` NHibernate throws a `NonUniqueObjectException`.

I've found that one way of working around this issue is to get new copies of the objects with:

```
obj = session.Get(obj.GetType(), (obj as PersistentObject).Id);
```

instead of reattaching with `session.Lock`. However, this is non-optimal as some of the record sets are potentially quite large, and re-getting each object individually could become a performance drag.

The object which is non-unique is a referenced object that exists only on the `PersistentObject` class, and not the `UserSetting` class. So I cannot understand why a flush would cause this exception.

I've tried evicting the cached objects after the module is done with them, but this does not help.

Does anyone know of a better way to attach objects to the session that could avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use a fresh session (or transaction) for processing each item and for updating the UserSetting? This would probably prevent the NonUniqueException.

Cheers,

-Maarten

Comment: Doh! That's the obvious solution, and the one I should have thought of. Now I feel silly. ;)